# Setting background-image to an image with partial transparency

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to place one div with a partially transparent background (meaning regions of the image are blank -- not X% opacity) on top of another.

```
#about {
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/B922OoM.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: none;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 450px;
  width: 100%;      
}
```

I can't get the div to not fill with white behind the image.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4HAxu/ -- the relevant div is `#about`

(I'm pretty sure the image is exported properly -- if you change `background-color:transparent` to `background-color:blue`, you'll see what I mean.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is fine. 
It's the fact your `#header` doesn't actually extend down that far. If you change the background colour of your `body` you'll see it's not your `#about` div it's the `body` showing behind it that is white

[Red BG body JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HAxu/3/)

To alleviate this problem, if you actually overlay your `div`s you will get the effect I think you're trying to achieve.

[Overlayed divs with negative top margin](http://jsfiddle.net/4HAxu/4/)

Comment: as haxxxton said the image you have added is photoshoped in such a way that the top part is transparent hence it is showing the background of your body ......

Comment: with small updates to @haxxton answer if you add background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);  on #about  (free to change the rbba color value)  then it will be nearer to what Jason is looking for i guess . http://jsfiddle.net/4HAxu/6/

Comment: good pick up @cjmling i forgot about the "partial transparency" part of the question